# How to trigger download from web api .net core 6

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am generating a zip file, uploading it to Azure Blob Storage, and returning the URL to the client. The client then uses the URL, which is the endpoint itself, to trigger the API and initiate the download.

Now, the URL that I am generating is a TinyURL which will point to the actual URL that I have generated using Azure SAS Builder.

When I hit the TinyURL, it will call the API, look into the database, fetch the actual URL, and then download the file.

I want to download a file using a URI that triggers the download in the browser without loading the file into the browser.

Here is the code

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GenerateZipUri(FileDownloadRequest[] requests, string userId, string fileSaveAs, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        (string uri, string latestRev) = await CheckCustomUriAndLatestRev(userId, ct);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri)) return ApiResult.OKResult(body: uri);
        string tempFilePath = TempFileManager.CreateTempFile("zip");
        try
        {
            await CreateZipFile(requests, tempFilePath);
            await UploadZipFileToBlobStorage(userId, fileSaveAs, tempFilePath, ct);
            string customUrl = await GetCustomUrl(userId, fileSaveAs, latestRev, ct);
            return ApiResult.OKResult(body: customUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError(e, "Exception has been thrown while creating Zip from Azure Blob Storage");
            return ApiResult.InternalServerError(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            TempFileManager.DeleteTempFile(tempFilePath);
        }
    }

    private async Task<(string customUri, string latestRev)> CheckCustomUriAndLatestRev(string userId, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        string docId = $"tinyurl:{userId}";
        DocumentResponse response = await GetCustomUrlByUserId(docId, ct);
        TinyUrl tinyUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TinyUrl>(response.Content);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (tinyUrl.ExpiryDatetime > DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                return (tinyUrl.CustomUrl.ToString(), tinyUrl.Rev);
            }
        }
        return (string.Empty, tinyUrl.Rev);
    }

    private async Task CreateZipFile(FileDownloadRequest[] requests, string tempFilePath)
    {
        using FileStream tempFileStream = new(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create);
        await GetZipOfBlobFiles(requests, tempFileStream);
    }

    private async Task UploadZipFileToBlobStorage(string userId, string fileSaveAs, string tempFilePath, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        FileUploadRequest fileUploadRequest = new()
        {
            Container = userId,
            Extension = "zip",
            Name = fileSaveAs,
            OwnerType = "",
            DocumentType = "file",
        };
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = await CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(userId);
        string blobName = $"{fileSaveAs}.{fileUploadRequest.Extension}";
        using FileStream tempFileStream = new(tempFilePath, FileMode.Open);
        await UploadBlobAsync(blobContainerClient, tempFileStream, blobName, SetMetaData(fileUploadRequest), ct);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetCustomUrl(string userId, string fileSaveAs, string latestRev, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = new(AppConfig.BlobStorageConnectionString, userId, $"{fileSaveAs}.zip");
        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = CreateBlobSasBuilder(userId, $"{fileSaveAs}.zip");
        TinyUrl doc = new(userId)
        {
            Rev = latestRev,
            ActualUrl = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder),
            ExpiryDatetime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            CustomUrl = CreateURI("/filetransfer/file/downloadfile", userId),
        };
        CouchWrapper couch = new(azureConfig);
        DocumentHeaderResponse headerResponse = await couch.UpsertDocumentAsync(doc.Id, doc.ToJson(), ct);
        return doc.CustomUrl.ToString();
    }
    private Uri CreateURI(string path, string userId)
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new(AppConfig.BaseUrl)
        {
            Path = path,
            Query = $"{nameof(userId)}={userId}",
        };
        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }

    private BlobSasBuilder CreateBlobSasBuilder(string userId, string blobName)
    {
        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new()
        {
            BlobContainerName = userId,
            BlobName = blobName,
            Resource = "b",
            StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            Protocol = SasProtocol.Https,
        };
        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);
        return sasBuilder;
    }
```

any help would be appericiated
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used the below code and able to do in API.

```
[HttpPost(nameof(DownloadFile))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(string fileName)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob MycloudBlockBlob;
            await using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                string blobstorageconnection = @"Connection String";
                CloudStorageAccount MycloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobstorageconnection);
                CloudBlobClient cloudClient = MycloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudClient.GetContainerReference("Container Name");
                MycloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                await MycloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            }

            Stream MyblobStream = MycloudBlockBlob.OpenReadAsync().Result;
            return File(MyblobStream, MycloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType, MycloudBlockBlob.Name);
        }
```

I uploaded the file in azure.

[image]

And able to download it.

[image]

Comment: Why do you download the blob to a memoryStream ?

Comment: The problem still persists because when I call my endpoint instead of triggering a download, I am getting gibberish text which is the bytes of the file. @Rajesh M